# Keyboard shortcut to display error on line in Xcode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xcode

When a line of code contains an error, I normally have to click the red circle on the margin to view the details. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the **Jump to Next Issue** and **Jump to Previous Issue** commands on the **Navigate** menu, which have the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> respectively.

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to open the Issue Navigator, and then use <kbd>⬆</kbd> and <kbd>⬇</kbd> to highlight the error, which will also open the file and display the error details.